# Error while start Diaspora Pod - !! Invalid request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diaspora

```
 [root@v45050 diaspora]# ./script/server
```

> Using rack adapter
>   Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>   Maximum connections set to 1024
>   Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop 
>        ./script/../lib/diaspora/web_socket.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant           REDIS_CONNECTION_SET
>         Websocket server started.
>         !! Invalid request
>        !! Invalid request

Setup as developer

Answer (score 1):

I re-set-up the database and error the error is now gone.

Comment: found instructions here https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/FAQ-for-Developers